# Opening Java .class files in Ubuntu

Tags: java, class

I have a Java .class that I have to open and modify.

I got libbcel-java in Ubuntu 12.04 (using the Software Center), which according to some forums can be used to open the mentioned type of file.

The problem is that I can't find any information about how to use such package.

Can anyone provide information to use it? or any other option to open .class files is also welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: .class files are binary/compiled java files. What use case do you have to modify an already-compiled .class file?

Comment: @drobert OP want to open the .class file in ubuntu

Comment: And what information do you want when you "open" that file exactly?

Comment: I am following some directions to use internal and hidden classes for Android, and one step indicates that I need to modify a .class file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to edit a class file since it's a binary file. You can do that indirectly by doing the following.

1. Decompile the file using some decompiler like JAD or Mocha. You will get a `.java` file.
2. Modify the file.
3. Compile it with `javac` command. You will get a the modified `.class` file.

Answer (score 1):

You can also de-compile a Java class using javap ;

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html

Answer (score 1):

You can read a .class file using `javap` command

```
javap -c Test.class
```